# SearchBar and Xamarin.Form

Tags: xamarin.forms

Am working on a XF project which has a SearchBar. The XAML Declaration looks like following.

```
<SearchBar Placeholder="Result" Text="{Binding SearchedCustomer,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCustomerCommand}"></SearchBar>
```

At ViewModel, I have following declared

```
    private string _SearchedCustomer;
    public string SearchedCustomer
    {
        get { return _SearchedCustomer; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _SearchedCustomer, value); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand SearchCustomerCommand { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<CustomerModel> _CustomerList;
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerModel> CustomerList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_CustomerList == null)
                FillCustomerDetails();
            return _CustomerList;
        }
        set { SetProperty(ref _CustomerList, value); }
    }

    private void ExecuteSearchCustomerCommand()
    {
        var tempRecords = _CustomerList.Where(c => c.ReferenceText.Contains(SearchedCustomer));
        CustomerList.Clear();
        foreach (var item in tempRecords)
        {
            CustomerList.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

I also have the SearchCustomerCommand created in the Constructor as following

```
SearchCustomerCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteSearchCustomerCommand).ObservesProperty(()=> SearchedCustomer);
```

When I type in the SearchBar, the SearchedCustomer Fields gets changed, however, the Command SearchCustomerCommand is not executed.

Could someone help me in identifying what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the Command is only fired when the Done/Return button is pressed

Comment: Thanks Gerald. I was under impression it will be invoked on keystrokes.

Comment: Hi Gerald, that did work as you mentioned, however, the application seems crashes once the search command is successfully executed.

Comment: It seems you do not initialise the `CustomerList` object

Comment: Hi Gerald. In fact I do, the function, FillCustomerDetails() called in  property CustomerList takes care of filling it up. When I debug after hitting the enter key in search bar, I can see the results being populated within the ExecuteSearchCustomerCommand Method, but the moment the function exists, the application crashes.

Comment: Do you have any details about the crash? Stack traces? Error message?